# Tidy up an Excel sheet using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel sheet with over 40,000 rows.  The first column is is datetime, and has a value for every minute.

I want to reduce this to give me the reading every 15 minutes.

I've tried the following code:

```
data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
data = data.resample('15T', on='Datetime').sum()
data.to_excel('new_file.xlsx')
```

Obviously, that's giving me readings every 15 minutes, but it's (obviously) totalling up the values for each 15 minute period.  I don't want this...  I just want to remove the values inbetween 0 and 15, 15 and 29, etc.

[Spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvDNV.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `'Datetime'` the index of `data`? Then you don't need to resample: `data = data.asfreq('15T')` should do it. Otherwise `data = data.set_index('Datetime').asfreq('15T')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)

series.resample('3T').interpolate()
```

where interpolate will give you a guess where the 15 min data item is missing

so in your example, it would be

```
data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
data = data.resample('15T', on='Datetime').interpolate()
data.to_excel('new_file.xlsx')
```